# Me esta saltando casi todos los scanf de mi programa

Tags: c, scanf

Estoy haciendo un programa en C que compare dos excursiones por la montaña e indique cuál de ellas es la más exigente sigundo el siguiente criterio: Una excursión será más exigente que otra si su desnivel positivo acumulado es superior. En caso de empate, la más exigente será la que tenga mayor distancia. En caso de empate, la más exigente será la que se haya introducido primero. El problema sala a la hora de ejecutar el programa ya que me esta saltando algunos scanf:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2uT1.png
(es la foto de como me esta imprimiendo el programa)

No tengo idea de porque hace esto pero aquí esta el condigo:

````
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 15

typedef struct {
    char nombre[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    float distancia;
    int desnivel;
} texcursion;

int main(){
int rutaexigente=2;
    
    texcursion primera, segunda;
    
    printf("INPUT\n");
    
        printf("ROUTE 1\n");
        
    printf("NAME?\n");
    scanf("%c",primera.nombre);
    getchar();
    
    printf("DISTANCE?\n");  
    scanf(" %f",&primera.distancia);
    
    
    printf("CUMULATIVE ELEVATION DIFFERENCE?\n");
    scanf(" %d",&primera.desnivel);

printf("ROUTE 2\n");
        
    printf("NAME?\n");
    scanf("%c",segunda.nombre);
    getchar();
    
    printf("DISTANCE?\n");  
    scanf(" %f",&segunda.distancia);
    
    printf("CUMULATIVE ELEVATION DIFFERENCE?\n");
    scanf(" %d",&segunda.desnivel);

if(primera.desnivel>segunda.desnivel){
        rutaexigente=1;
    }else 
        if (primera.desnivel==segunda.desnivel){
            if(primera.distancia>segunda.distancia){
                rutaexigente=1;
            }else 
                if (primera.distancia==segunda.distancia){
                    rutaexigente=1;
            }
}
    printf("OUTPUT\n");
    if(rutaexigente==1){
        printf("THE HARDEST ROUTE IS %s\n",primera.nombre);
    }else{
        printf("THE HARDEST ROUTE IS %s\n",segunda.nombre);
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: Es culpa del primer `scanf("%c")`. Tras leer el carácter que teclees, deja sin leer el retorno de carro que pulsas después, y eso puede afectar a todos los `scanf()` posteriores. Prueba a poner un `getchar()` tras los scanf que lean un solo caracter, para "consumir" el retorno de carro pendiente.

Comment: Gracias por responder @abulafia , eso fue una de las primeras cosas que intente y que están aplicadas al código. Ademas de la aplicacion de `getchar()` tambien intente poner un espacio en el scanf asi: `scanf("  %f",&primera.distancia);` pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado el problema! y la verdad me siento un poco bobo por no darme cuenta antes, el problema es que esta utilizando  `%c` que es para caracteres en lugar de `%s` que es para cadenas de estos, cambiar esto soluciono todos los problemas. Gracias a todos los que dieron su tiempo para ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez el problema es que estás leyendo un carácter con el primer *scanf* y no estás vaciando el búfer de entrada antes de leer el resto de valores y eso provoca que se salte los *scanf's* siguientes. Intenta escribiendo *fflush(stdin)* antes de cada *scanf*.

Ejemplo:

```
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%c", primera.nombre);
/*getchar();*/ /*si no funciona prueba des-comentando esta linea*/

printf("DISTANCE?\n");

fflush(stdin);
scanf("%f", &primera.distancia);

printf("CUMULATIVE ELEVATION DIFFERENCE?\n");

fflush(stdin);
scanf(" %d",&primera.desnivel);
```

Comment: `fflush()` solo hace algo en un flujo de salida. No hace nada si lo aplicas sobre `stdin`, o como mínimo su comportamiento es indefinido porque no está estandarizado.